# iOS 6 Twitter share without using system account

Tags: ios, ios6, twitter

On a current project I would like to let a user that does NOT have a Twitter account setup login and tweet. Use case: this area of the app is being used by many different end users as part of a check-in process. It is not their personal iPad, they just use it for about 10 minutes to check-in for an event. During that check-in process I want to let them share to FB and Twitter if they choose.

I was able to accomplish the Facebook share without using the system account using Facebook's `presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession` API, which works great. Is there a similar API in the Twitter SDK? Is there another way I could do this that leverages the Social or Twitter framework?

Recommendations greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with the built-in twitter SDK.  You will need to use the "old" way of doing this, which is via oAuth or xAuth.  A good framework for this can be found on github called [FHSTwitterEngine](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine).  You will need to make your own UI for what you do with twitter itself, but it handles the login/authentication for you as much as possible.

Also [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) may be useful to find other 3rd party frameworks (that is updated by twitter themselves) if you need to go outside of their regular SDK and the above does not get you what you want.